# How to raise error in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, exception, roo-gem

I'm trying to upload a file using gem 'roo'. When I check for file of type, I have this in a instance method:

```
def open_spreadsheet
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
    when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
    when ".ods" then Roo::LibreOffice.new(file.path,file_warning: :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type"
  end
end
```

Is there a way to catch this exception so that user sees just message and gets to try again, without actually raising syntax error?

Comment: Is this in a controller?

Comment: What? This method? No, it's in a model.

Answer (score -1):

You can have catch block

```
begin
  # call methods
rescue ErrorType => error_object
  # handle the error
end
```

You can also define transaction inside `begin rescue` block

```
begin
   ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
     # call methods
   end
rescue ErrorType => error_object
  # handle the error
end
```

Only if no error occurs methods will be persisted to db

Also check [Rails errors](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rescue-standarderror-not-exception)

Comment: How would that look like with this specific code? Since I would have rescue in the middle of case statement?

Comment: You put your method inside `begin`, where you call `open_spreadsheet`. Put `open_spreadsheet` inside `begin` block

Comment: And do I keep the raise line?

Comment: Yes. When method `open_spreadsheet` gets called from `begin` block it will perform its syntax, and if no matching file type you want method to throw the error. When it throws error `rescue` block will catch it, and you can do with the message what you like